# Suck at JavaScript and overall just a beginner in the dev world. Whats the best way to begin building DApps?

Tags: dapps

Suck at JavaScript and overall just a beginner in the dev world. Whats the best way to begin building DApps? The title is my question LOL.

Comment: Getting rid of your suckness would be a good place to start.

Comment: @goodvibration Good advice though.

Would advise you to look at cryptozombies.io for some tutorials

Comment: Very cool, just checked out the zombies thing. Looks legit. Any more advice would be appreciated. I also kind of don't get what its about. Seems like a confusing subject but my gut tells me that it's worth getting into.

Comment: Developing apps is not limited to JS, there are multiple languages who provide wrapper for interacting with the ethereum Blockchain:
Golang --> Geth Code/ abigen ;
.net --> Nethereum;
Java --> web3j